# ¿Existe alguna consulta entre dos tablas que me devuelva todos los datos de ambas tablas aunque una no tenga datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas un horario y un detalle de horario.

El detalle horario tiene una llave foránea de mi tabla horario y  cuando hago la consulta con `inner join` me trae los registros, todo bien. Pero, cuando hago una inserción solo al horario no me lo muestra.

No sé si hay una forma de traer registro de de otras tablas aunque no existan un registro no importa que se queden en nulos.

Los id de mis tablas son el id de mi horario que es la llave foránea de mi detalle horario y esta la represento con id_h_laboral

Anexo una imagen del código SQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta sql

```sql
SELECT  horario_laboral.id,horario_laboral.fecha_inicial,horario_laboral.fecha_final,horario_laboral.id 
,detalle_horario.id_h_laboral,
MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Lunes'  THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Lunes,
MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Martes'  THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Martes,
MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Miercoles' THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Miercoles,
 MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Jueves'  THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Jueves,
 MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Viernes' THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Viernes,
 MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Sabado'    THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Sabado,
 MAX( CASE WHEN dia = 'Domingo' THEN detalle_horario.dia ELSE NULL END) AS Domingo
FROM horario_laboral  inner join  detalle_horario
ON horario_laboral.id=detalle_horario.id
 GROUP BY detalle_horario.id_h_laboral ORDER BY id_h_laboral desc;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Este sitio es de código y no de imágenes, para postear imágenes ya existe Instagram o cualquier otra red antisocial. Haz clic en [edit] y copia y pega el código en tu pregunta. Además haría falta un poco de información sobre las claves de tus tablas, podrías copiar y pegar el DDL de las mismas. Saludos

Comment: Qué tal [LEFT JOIN o RIGHT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)?

Comment: ya lo intente pero la cosa es que no me regresa los datos

Comment: ¿Probaste con `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: pero en este caso si tengo hacer referencia a los id

Comment: si lo acabe de probar pero la cosa es que si me regresa  los datos  pero por ejemplo si aun no tengo un registro en horario  y esa no tiene ningun dato  en comun con detalle_horario  no me muestra ese  nuevo registro

Comment: @Marcos tiene razon te falta donde el FROM

Comment: si de echo yo agregue  tambien el inner join

Comment: Esto con left join deberia funcionar o rigth join debria anda.r...

Comment: El problema es que quieres traer todos los datos de AMBAS tablas y a la vez quieres `agrupar` por algo que probablemente ni exista, como es `detalle_horario.id_h_laboral`. Dado que lo que quieres hacer no parece quedar muy claro, considera reproducir tus dos tablas en http://sqlfiddle.com/ para que sea más fácil ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Comment: si de echo debo agrupar   pero ya lo puedo revisar por que cambie la agrupación

Comment: podrías añadir a la pregunta tus dos tablas al ser posibles con sus columnas @RodrigoGuzman para ayuda mejor

Comment: si ya las agrego

Comment: Si quieres que se muestre aunque no te ga datos, coloca un left join en lugar de inner join